# Cancelling Parallel.For with CancellationToken using method

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token, parallel.for

I need to Cancel all Tasks made by Parallel.For when using function.
For example:

```
class Example
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    public Example()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
    public void plsCompute()
    {
        ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions{ CancellationToken = cts.Token };
        Parallel.For(0, 10, po, (i) => compute());
    }

    public void plsStopComputing()
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }

    public void compute()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
            if(//token was cancelled){
                Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
                return;
            }
            //do something
        }
    }
```

I need to stop all task that are currently runing, not creating new tasks.

Is there any way to achieve this?

All examples I've seen was with function made in lambda, so there I could access cts. I need it to be in other funtion. Also if I passed token as a parameter it didnt work. cts token was changed but in other threads it didnt change.

Any help appriciated :)

## EDIT

As I mentioned in comment, I got deeper, this example is not really what I want. These methods are invoked by messeges sent through msmq from an wpf app. I think that every time I call from wpf, service makes new instance of this class, so it cancels new instance instead of the one that is already computing.
Is there a way to call the same instance?

Comment: Can't you simply pass in the token? `(i) => compute(i, cts.Token)`?

Comment: As I said, it looks like its passed to other threads as copy. Changing it in main thread do not change it in other threads

Comment: `CancellationToken` is a struct so, yes, it'll be passed a copy. But that struct contains a reference to the original `CancellationTokenSource`. So what's the problem?

Comment: Even if I passed CancellationTokenSource it passed it as a copy..

Comment: You must be doing something wrong because it should definitely work. Can you post a compilable reproduction?

Comment: Ok, as I got deeper, this example is not really what I want. 
These methods are invoked by messeges sent through msmq from an wpf app. I think that every time I call from wpf, service makes new instance of this class, so it cancels new instance instead of the one that is already computing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with invoking by msmq, that every time message was received it created new instance of class. 
I've solved it adding

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

Above declaration of class that implements service